# Deploy an installer package using click once

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, deployment, clickonce

I am using a WPF based windows application which contains multiple dll's and single exe file. I have created an installer package using NSIS and signed the installer with Authenticode as well. I would like to use Click once for the same. Any way to deploy an existing installer package with click once? or if I am creating a new package with click once, how to include multiple dll's, external xml files along with signing

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to your exact question, but you could have a look at Squirrel. For me that's 'Click Once Next Level'. 
Both (Click Once and Squirrel) require a new package, and both can be signed. Click Once from Visual Studio, Squirrel in your script to create the package.